# Regarding rate dependence on redox potential

Tags: reaction-mechanism, redox, kinetics

I am stuck with an equation wherein chloroauric acid reacts with oxalic acid to form Au(s). Even though one of both are enough for the reaction:

- How does the rate change with increased oxalic acid?
- Does it have anything to do with low reduction potential of oxalic acid?